# Why the content is not printing inside the system.out.println statement while using a boolean statement

Tags: java, string, system.out

Data is not displaying inside the system.out.println statement

with parenthesis it is working and equals method

```
final String s1="all men are created equal:27";
final String s2="all men are created equal:"+s1.length();
System.out.println("all men are created equal:" + (s1==s2));
```

output: all men are created equal:false

```
final String s1="all men are created equal:27";
final String s2="all men are created equal:"+s1.length();
System.out.println("all men are created equal:" + (s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2)));
System.out.println();
```

output:all men are created equal:false

```
final String s1="all men are created equal:27";
final String s2="all men are created equal:"+s1.length();
System.out.println("all men are created equal:" + s1==s2);
System.out.println();
```

output:false

Why is the "all men are created equal:" is not printing

Answer (score 2):

The operators you are using have different *precedences*. The `==` operator has a lower precedence than the `+` operator (just like how `+` has a lower precedence than `*` in maths), so your expression

```
"all men are created equal:" + s1==s2
```

gets parsed this way:

```
("all men are created equal:" + s1) == s2
```

It is comparing whether `"all men are created equal:" + s1` is equal to `s2`. The result of this expression is a `boolean`. Therefore, only `false` is printed.

By adding the parenthesis, you are making it clear that you want the `s1==s2` part to be evaluated *first*, then the `+` operator. This is just like how `1+2*3` is different from `(1+2)*3`.

Also note that you should compare strings with `equals`, not `==`:

```
"all men are created equal:" + s1.equals(s2)
```

The `.` operator has a very high precedence, higher than that of `+`, so you don't need the brackets in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The last print is showing only false because of the operator precedence in java. At first it concats the "all men are created equal:" with string s1. Then it compares if the concated string is equal to s2 and prints the output. As you can see the concated string is not equal to s2.

Answer (score 0):

Just because `"all men are created equal:" + s1` and `s2` isn't equal.

With the above expression you are checking whether `"all men are created equal:" + s1` and `s2` is equal or not. Since `"all men are created equal:" + s1` and `s2` isn't equal, the result will be `false`.

if you want to get the expected behavior, you should use parenthesis around `s1==s2`.

```
"all men are created equal:" + (s1==s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "()" to s1==s2.
Like this:

```
System.out.println("all men are created equal:" + (s1==s2));
```

The reason is following:

```
"all men are created equal:" + s1 => "all men are created equal:false"
"all men are created equal:false" == s2 => false
PRINT false
```